# Как быстро расчитать среднее арифметическое, геометрическое и гармоническое для разности остортированных элементов каждой строки в таблице?

Tags: python, pandas, оптимизация, numpy, обработка-данных

Как быстро и эффективно расчитать среднее арифметическое, геометрическое и гармоническое для разности остортированных элементов каждой строки в таблице с 100 миллионами строк?

В случае если разность двух элементов одной строки равна нулю, то ноль нужно заменить на 1 для подсчета среднего.

Ниже приведен код. Работает только подсчет `ndf['r1']` но и он очень медленный из-за `apply`. Не знаю, как также быстро подсчитать среднее геомитрическое и гармоническое.

```
import pandas as pd
import math

lst = [[1,23,45],[20,30,10],[60,15,2]]

df = pd.DataFrame(lst, columns = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']) 
print(df)
ndf = pd.DataFrame()


ndf['r1'] = df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(list(x.sort_values())),axis=1).diff(axis=1).iloc[:,1:].mean(axis=1)
#ndf['r2'] = (10 ** df.apply(lambda x: x.sort_values(),axis=1).diff(axis=1).iloc[:,1:].applymap(math.log10).sum(axis=1)) ** (1/len(columns)) 
#ndf['r3'] = len(df.columns)/( (1/df.diff(axis=1).iloc[:,1:]).sum(axis=1) )

print(ndf)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример данных:

```
from scipy.stats import gmean, hmean

df = pd.DataFrame([[1,23,45],[20,30,10],[60,15,2],[45,1,1]])

In [91]: df
Out[91]:
    0   1   2
0   1  23  45
1  20  30  10
2  60  15   2
3  45   1   1  # <--- пример строки, где разность двух элементов одной строки равна нулю
```

векторизированное решение с использованием `Numpy` и `SciPy`:

```
# матрица разностей остортированных элементов каждой строки в таблице
a = np.diff(np.sort(df, axis=1), axis=1)
# замена 0 --> 1
a[a==0] = 1
res = pd.DataFrame({
    "mean": np.mean(a, axis=1),
    "gmean": gmean(a, axis=1),
    "hmean": hmean(a, axis=1)
}, index=df.index)
```

результат:

```
In [92]: res
Out[92]:
   mean      gmean      hmean
0  22.0  22.000000  22.000000
1  10.0  10.000000  10.000000
2  29.0  24.186773  20.172414
3  22.5   6.633250   1.955556
```